# How to enable remote (mobile) user at login time?

Tags: macos, login, login-screen

I used to be able to login with my Active Directory Credentials at boot time.

But after the upgrade to Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) I can't see the remote login anymore. I have to log in with a local account and then logout in order to be able to log in against the AD.

Any clue how can I make remote login available every time?

Comment: I don't know if you solved this, but does your system use FileVault 2 perchance?

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing this issue after an upgrade today and adding the machine to Active Directory. It then occurred to me that my FileVault setup is causing this; FileVault 2 is full disk encryption, so the local account "unlocks" the drive and allows access to the configuration necessary to allow network users to log in.

My guess is this is part of the design/implementation of the encryption, if you have that enabled. Disabling FV2 may allow the login process to work with network users. I need to do more testing.